# dBaseIV file creation from SQL Server 2016 database

Tags: sql-server-2016, dbf

I have a requirement as follows: on click of a link button on a web page, I have to fetch some records from a SQL Server 2016 database and convert them into dBaseIV format (.env, .ad1, .ad2, .veh) files and show a download/save as popup on the page where the end user would be able to download the files individually.

Any leads would be appreciated.

[dBaseIV files expected on click of link button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THok1.png)

Comment: In what language - php, asp.net, windows iis ?

Comment: code is to be written in asp.net

Comment: would have to be operating server in 32bit mode, but not that hard

Comment: Operating System is in 64 bit, windows 10. Also, I'm using visual studio 2017 for code development.

Comment: Using .Net Framework 4.7.2 and VS2017

Comment: In 64 bit mode would be hard, you would have to write your own translation, under 32bit mode you could use the FoxPRO ODBC interface
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn170517(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: David, I wrote the connection string in web.config and I'm using the key to establish the connection to the database and moreover I'm using SQL db, not oracle db.

Comment: that's for the SQL Server - or ODBC, I don't think FoxPRO driver is 64bit compatible. DBASE IV - not sure on that status

Comment: If it is compatible the syntax is pretty basic CREATE TABLE sort of stuff

Comment: The files are to be created at application end and not the database. Let me explain you the flow -- 1) click the link on webpage 2) fetch records from database 3) create dBaseIV files 4) put the records fetched into these files 5) show a download popup on application screen to save these files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is like 90's requirement - a lot from memory ...

This is a VS 2017 console app ..., creates a DBaseIV file called bill and inserts a record, of course the logic to create, read etc is not included - also

- System.IO.File.Exists is of dubious reliability on 64bit systems - someone else might have a better solution
- I don't use IIS - so no idea on how to setup downloads there
- and - I ran this on a Dell Windows 10 machine, the dBaseIV driver existed in ODBC

  Module Module1

  ```
  Sub Main()
      Dim connectionString As String = "Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};DBQ=C:\temp\"
      Using cn As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(connectionString)

          cn.Open()

          If Not System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Temp\books.dbf") Then
              Using cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("CREATE TABLE BOOKS (title char(50))", cn)
                  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

              End Using

          End If

          Using cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO BOOKS (title) VALUES('The Story of Bill')", cn)
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

          End Using

          cn.Close()

      End Using

      Console.Write("done")
      Console.ReadKey()

  End Sub
  ```

  End Module